# List in Prolog with elements in round brackets

Tags: list, prolog

Good Morning

I have list similiar to this: `[(1-4), (2-4), (3-4)]`. I'd like to write only first/second/third part of round bracket. I wrote a function:

```
write_list([]).

write_list([Head|Tail]) :-
  write(Head), nl,
  write_list(Tail).
```

It only writes whole round bracket:
1-4
2-4
3-4

I'd like my output to be the 1st element of round bracket:
1
2
3

I'll be grateful for any help :D

Comment: Please show an example of a query. Your general description of what you're trying to achieve isn't clear. Also note that Prolog has *predicates*, not *functions*. They are not the same thing.

Comment: When i use:      write_list([(1-4),(2-4),(3-4)]). the output is as follow: 1-4  2-4  3-4. I'd like my output to be the 1st number of the round bracket, for the list [(1-4),(2-4),(3-4)] it would be:    1              2                       3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
write_list([]).
write_list([(A-_)|Tail]) :-
  writeln(A),
  write_list(Tail).
```

Query:

```
?- write_list([(1-4),(2-4),(3-4)]).
1
2
3
true
```

`writeln/1`  is simply `write/1`  followed by `nl` .

Comment: If this answer satisfy your request, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to `write` the results but provide them as an argument. Many beginners in Prolog get stuck on this point. Also, it's such a common pattern to apply the same logic to each list element that Prolog has a predicate called `maplist` for doing the work for you:

```
first_subterm(A-_, A).   % First subterm of `A-_` is `A`

first_subterms(PairList, FirstSubTerms) :-
    maplist(first_subterm, PairList, FirstSubTerms).
```

And you would call it like so:

```
| ?- first_subterms([(1-4), (2-4), (3-4)], FirstSubTerms).

FirstSubTerms = [1,2,3]

yes
| ?-
```

The long-hand recursive form would be similar to what was given in the other answer:

```
first_subterms([], []).  % The list of first subterms of [] is []
first_subterms([(A-_)|Pairs], [A|SubTerms]) :-
    first_subterms(Pairs, SubTerms).
```

Note that the "round brackets" are *parentheses* and, in Prolog, in this context only perform a grouping of the term. It turns out that `[(1-4), (2-4), (3-4)]` here behaves the same, therefore, as `[1-4, 2-4, 3-4]` since the `,` is lower precedence than `-` in the list notation. So this is also the behavior:

```
| ?- first_subterms([1-4, 2-4, 3-4], FirstSubTerms).

FirstSubTerms = [1,2,3]

yes
| ?-
```