# Prolog, how to add items from one list to second

Tags: list, prolog

Good Morning
I have a list in following format:

```
[(1-4),(2-4), (3-4)]
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
[4,3,4,2,4,1]
```

I have tried 2 programs:

```
changeList([], Z) :- 
    write(Z).
changeList([(A-B)|T], Z) :-
    append([A], Z, Y),
    append([B], Y, X),
    changeList(T, X).
```

and the second one:

```
changeList([],Z) :-
    write(Z).
changeList([(X-Y)|T], Z) :-
    W = [X|Z],
    C = [Y|W],
    changeList(T,C).
```

Sadly the result is always:  [4,3,4,2,4,1|_38]. Where do i make a mistake?

Comment: The call to `write/1` is where your mistake is.

Comment: So you want them to merge and in backwards order?

Comment: reply to  Seppe Mariën: yes exactly like u say, reply to  Tomas By: so how can i change it to write list without |38???

Comment: Why are you mixing `write` statements with returning results as arguments?  As I mentioned in [a prior answer to a similar question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130976/list-in-prolog-with-elements-in-round-brackets#answer-48132322), you shouldn't use `write` for providing predicate results. `changeList([], Z) :- write(Z).` does not establish a value for `Z` and doesn't make sense. It says that if you change the list `[]` you get any result you want, `Z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with different metods. If you want to get the list in reverse order, you need a further input variable which is an empty list. Using your code you can write:

```
changeList([],Z,Z).
changeList([(A-B)|T],Acc,Z) :-
    append([A], Acc, Y),
    append([B], Y, X),
    changeList(T,X,Z).

?- changeList([(1-4),(2-4),(3-4)],[],Z).
Z = [4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1]
```

You can avoid the use of `append/3` in this way:

```
myReverse([],Z,Z).
myReverse([(A-B)|T],Acc,Z):- 
    myReverse(T,[B,A|Acc],Z).

?- myReverse([(1-4),(2-4),(3-4)],[],Z).
Z = [4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1]
```

You have another solution which is to print the list in an ordered way, then reverse it using built-in predicate (in SWI) `reverse/2`:

```
changeListOrd([],[]).
changeListOrd([(A-B)|T], [A,B|TL]):-
    changeListOrd(T,TL).
change(L,Lout):-
    changeListOrd(L,L1),
    reverse(L1,Lout).

?- change([(1-4),(2-4),(3-4)],Z).
Z = [4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1]
```

I suggest you to go with the second solution (`myReverse/3`) so you don't need both `append/3` and `reverse/2`.

Answer (score 0):

**foldl/4** is a friend for you :

```
changeList(In, Out) :-
    foldl(reverse_one, In, [], Out).

reverse_one((X-Y), In, [Y,X|In]).
```

Example :

```
?- changeList([(1-4),(2-4),(3-4)],Out).
Out = [4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1].
```